# Is it correct to say "On vacation till forever"?

Tags: vocabulary

Is it correct to say

> "On vacation till forever"

or should it be the following?

> "on vacation forever"

Comment: Could you at minimum write a sentence with the phrase you are asking about in it? Or otherwise tell us what context you have in mind for the phrase?

Answer (score 1):

Both are acceptable, although I think it's "**'til** forever" (short for "until") and not "till".  Another variation:

> On vacation 'til whenever.

I'll add more as I think of them.

Edit:  Apparently "till" is fine in place of "until".

Comment: You're right about them both being acceptable, but *till* is in fact a valid word: http://www.englishgrammar.org/until-and-till/

Comment: @stangdon thanks, I stand corrected.  I was thinking of the various other definitions of "till".

Comment: I disagree, *forever* comes about from the combination of the preposition *for* and the word *ever*, as such, you ought to be able to vaguely swap *forever* for *for ever*. '*On vacation till/until for ever*' makes no sense.

Comment: @BladorthinTheGrey I won't argue that the expression is *perfect*, but it would be perfectly understandable (and not that weird) if a native speaker were to use it.  Native speakers say nonsensical things all the time.

Comment: Etymological fallacy, @BladorthinTheGrey. The origin of a word gives you no reliable guide whatever to its meaning, usage, or grammatical function.

Comment: What about the next option as 'On vacation for good'?

Comment: @Max  that's not an uncommon expression, although I would be more likely to hear "on permanent vacation".  Which can either be nice or nasty, depending on context.

Answer (score 0):

> On vacation forever

Is correct here.

Since *forever* comes from the combination of the preposition 'for' and the word 'ever', you ought to be able to vaguely swap *forever* for *for ever*:

> On vacation till/until for ever

This sentence makes no sense at all and is, in fact, flagged as grammatically incorrect by my grammar checker.

> On vacation for ever

This makes perfect sense and so should be used in your sentence.

Comment: I think that "on vacation forever" is preferable, but I disagree that "...until forever" makes no sense.  It's perfectly understandable, if not formal.  On vacation until Tuesday, on vacation until the end of the week, on vacation until next year, on vacation until forever!

Comment: @stangdon But 'forever' is not a time period, you could not say 'one forever' unless it was tongue-in-cheek.

Comment: That's quite true, but I'm not sure it's relevant - we don't refer to all times the same way anyhow: I will be back *on* Tuesday, *in* one week, *at* dawn, etc.

Comment: +1 for "on vacation forever", -1 for everything after that

Comment: While "till forever" is not standard, there are 51 instances of "till/until forever" on the GloWbE corpus, so it has some currency. It is exactly like "for free", in that the preposition is redundant, but could have spread from similar constructions. On another point, it is simply not true that "**Since forever comes from the combination of the preposition 'for' and the word 'ever'**, you ought to be able to vaguely swap forever for for ever:": you can in this case, but try doing it to _without_ or _understand_!

Answer (score 0):

Technically, you should say *On vacation forever* since *until X* is meant to express an upper limit of something, and *forever* means there is no limit (of time).

However, by saying *until forever*, you are acknowledging/signifying that an upper limit on your vacation is important, requested, or required, but you are intentionally disregarding this and still not going to limit your vacation.  So it's fine to use if you mean that.

Answer (score 0):

A bit tongue-in-cheek, but in the military and Department of Defense circles, this is sometimes referred to as "terminal leave," meaning that you are on leave (vacation) until you die.

A more concise way to say this is that you are 'retired'. This is more acceptable than any form of 'vacation forever.'

Answer (score 0):

There's a slight difference between the sentences but they are still synonyms:

1. "On vacation till forever" - *Means **up to a very long time (forever)**.*
2. "On vacation forever" - *Means **for all future time; for always**.*

**Till** is just an informal way of saying **until**. However, **[till](https://www.merriam-webster.com/words-at-play/should-you-use-until-or-till-or-til)** is not a shortening of **until**.

**[’Til](https://www.grammarly.com/blog/until-till-til/)** turns up now and then, but major usage dictionaries and style guides consider it an error, so it’s best to avoid it.

Possible variants:

- Ever on vacation. - Means that *someone is always on vacation*.
- On vacation until forever ends. - An idiomatic way of saying *"for all eternity"*.
- On vacation until (for all) eternity. - The same as the above.
- On vacation until the end of time. - For eternity.
- On vacation forevermore. - For ever.
- On vacation for ever. - The same as the above.
- On vacation [for good](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/for+good).
- On an everlasting vacation.

Some very uncommon but idiomatic ways:

- On vacation [until hell freezes over](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/until+hell+freezes+over).
- On vacation [until doomsday](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/until+doomsday). - **Till Doomsday** is also possible.
- On vacation [until the cows come home](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/until+the+cows+come+home).
- On vacation [until kingdom come](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/until+kingdom+come).
- On vacation until (till) [forever and a day](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/forever).
- On vacation till time stops.
- On vacation [for aye](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/for%20aye). - *[SCOTTISH] Archaic*